# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) Django

Tags: django

Not sure why but my code is getting the following error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Here is my models.py:

```
class UserList(models.Model):
    list_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.list_name
```

Here is my views.py

```
def otherUserList(request):
    userName = request.GET.get('userName', None)
    print(userName)
    qs = UserList.objects.filter(user__username=userName)
    return qs
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /electra/otheruserlist/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 116, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 418, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 942, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 962, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 969, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1358, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1377, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1255, in build_filter
    arg, value = filter_expr
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
[02/Sep/2021 05:38:43] "GET /electra/otheruserlist/?userName=alice HTTP/1.1" 500 94227
```

I'd be very grateful for any assistance.

Comment: You can not return a `QuerySet`, a view should always return a HTTP response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view is returning a `QuerySet`, but that does not make much sense: a view should return a `HttpResponse`. You can for example render a template, convert it to JSON, etc.

We can for example render a template with:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def otherUserList(request):
    userName = request.GET.get('userName', None)
    qs = UserList.objects.filter(user__username=userName)
    return render(request, 'some-template.html', {'lists': qs})
```

Or we can for example return a `JsonResponse wit the` list_name`s of user the user with the given username with:

```
from django.http import JsonField

def otherUserList(request):
    userName = request.GET.get('userName', None)
    qs = UserList.objects.filter(user__username=userName)
    return JsonResponse({'listnames': [list.name for list in qs]})
```

Answer (score 2):

The exception comes from a Django internal middleware, since it's trying to process your returned `qs` as a response.

You'll need to return a response, not just a queryset, e.g. this simple example to return a list of user IDs.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def otherUserList(request):
    userName = request.GET.get('userName', None)
    print(userName)
    qs = UserList.objects.filter(user__username=userName)
    return JsonResponse({"ids": [user.id for user in qs]})
```